# Apache Jackrabbit JCR with Adobe Aem - "Workspace Mismatch"

Tags: java, adobe, jcr

I am experimenting with accessing Adobe AEM's JCR programmatically using the guide here: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-64/developing/platform/access-jcr.html?lang=en

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws RepositoryException {
        javax.jcr.Repository repository = JcrUtils
                .getRepository("https://example.com/crx/server");

        // Create a Session instance
        var session = repository
                .login(new SimpleCredentials("user", "user".toCharArray()));
        var root = session.getRootNode();
        var nIter = root.getNodes();
        while (nIter.hasNext()) {
            var n = (Node) nIter.next();
            System.out.println(n.getPath());
        }
```

However, I am getting the following error: `Workspace mismatch: 'https://example.com:443/crx/server/crx.default/jcr%3aroot/bin' not under workspace 'https://example.com/crx/server/crx.default' (position 41: '{https:/example.com}:443/crx/server/crx.default/jcr%3aroot/bin', expected: '/crx/server/crx.default')`

From the error (and confirmed by debugging), I can see that the mismatch is occurring because of the port (443) being include in the URI but not the workspace (the position 41 in the error is inaccurate simply because since I have removed the actual domain).

However, I am a bit perplexed as to why it is including the port. Obviously, I am not specifying the port when connecting and I am using the standard https port, so I am not sure how I can resolve this issue ?

Thanks!

Dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    // This dependency is exported to consumers, that is to say found on their compile classpath.
implementation 'org.apache.jackrabbit:jackrabbit-core:2.21.10'
implementation 'org.apache.jackrabbit:jackrabbit-jcr-commons:2.21.10'
implementation 'org.apache.jackrabbit:jackrabbit-api:2.19.3'
implementation 'org.apache.jackrabbit:jackrabbit-webdav:2.21.10'
implementation 'org.apache.sling:org.apache.sling.api:2.24.0'
implementation 'org.apache.sling:org.apache.sling.jcr.api:2.4.0'
compileOnly 'javax.jcr:jcr:2.0'

compileOnly 'org.apache.jackrabbit:jackrabbit-jcr2dav:2.21.10'


    // Use JUnit test framework
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue, i hope you are able to solve it by now,  but in my case the link was authored wrong and therefore it was appending in the url. Please check if the initial link is right.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).